# How do I use in-memory cache in Remix.run dev mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, remix.run

I need to fetch data from an API that is pretty slow and seldom changes, so I thought I'd use an in-memory cache. I first tried a very simple approach by just saving it to a variable outside the scope of the loader function in my route:

```
let cache;

export const loader = async () => {
  if (!cache) {
    // we always end up here
    cache = await (await fetch("...)).json()
  }
}
```

but that didn't work. I then tried a proper caching library (`lru-cache`), but that cache was also always empty. I then realized that the entired file got reloaded on each request which I guess is a dev mode thing, so I tried moving the creation of the cache to a separate file *cache.server.ts* and importing it from there.

```
import LRU from "lru-cache";
console.log("Creating cache"); // this is logged on each request
const cache = new LRU({ max: 200 });
export default cache;
```

But that file also seems to be reloaded on each request.

If I build a production version and run that everything works great, but it would be nice to have some way of getting it to work in dev mode as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remix purges the `require` cache on every request in development to support `<LiveReload/>`. To make sure your cache survives these purges, you need to assign it to the `global` object.

**EDIT: Here's a better way to handle this**

```js
// utils/singleton.server.ts

// since the dev server re-requires the bundle, do some shenanigans to make
// certain things persist across that 
// Borrowed/modified from https://github.com/jenseng/abuse-the-platform/blob/2993a7e846c95ace693ce61626fa072174c8d9c7/app/utils/singleton.ts

export function singleton<Value>(name: string, value: () => Value): Value {
    const yolo = global as any
    yolo.__singletons ??= {}
    yolo.__singletons[name] ??= value()
    return yolo.__singletons[name]
}
```

```js
// utils/prisma.server.ts

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { singleton } from './singleton.server.ts'

const prisma = singleton('prisma', () => new PrismaClient())
prisma.$connect()

export { prisma }
```

Comment: Does this only work when instantiating a class? As in, using a function like [memoizee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee) I don't need to worry about the require cache being purged? Or do I instead, need to provide the memoized function on the global object, rather than the `memoizee` function itself.

Comment: I looked, and it appears the `memoize` would lose its cache if the require cache was purged. So I would recommend you use the `singleton` function above.
`const memoize = singleton('memoize', () => require('memoize'))`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply and for updating your answer, it is appreciated! I had adapted the `prisma` approach mentioned by @soderlind, however I will look at updating to this.

Answer (score 6):

As a follow up on [Kilimans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72662281/1434155), here's how I did it:

```js
/*
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache
 */
import NodeCache from "node-cache";
let cache: NodeCache;

declare global {
  var __cache: NodeCache | undefined;
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  cache = new NodeCache();
} else {
  if (!global.__cache) {
    global.__cache = new NodeCache();
  }
  cache = global.__cache;
}

export { cache };
```

And I used it in the loader:

```js
import { getGitHubRepos } from "~/models/github.server";
import { cache } from "~/utils/cache";

export async function loader(args: LoaderArgs) {
  if (cache.has("GitHubRepos")) {
    return json(cache.get("GitHubRepos"));
  }
  const repos = await getGitHubRepos();
  cache.set("GitHubRepos", repos, 60 * 60 * 24);
  return json(repos);
}
```

Comment: What file do you put the first snippet to make sure it runs on server-start?

Answer (score 0):

I did this to have it at the server side as well. Make a file with the following content and call it wherever you want to use it.

```js
import NodeCache from 'node-cache';
let cache: NodeCache;

declare global {
  var __cache: NodeCache | undefined;
}

export default function getNodeCache() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    cache = new NodeCache();
  } else {
    if (!global.__cache) {
      global.__cache = new NodeCache();
    }
    cache = global.__cache;
  }

  return cache;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from [Kiliman's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72662281/1434155), here's how I did it using the [micro-memoize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/micro-memoize) package with TypeScript:

```
import type memoize from "micro-memoize";
import { singleton } from "~/utils/singleton.server";
type Memoizer = typeof memoize;

const memoizer: Memoizer = singleton("memoize", () => require("micro-memoize"));
export { memoizer as memoize };
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who's having the same issue and wants to use something more modern than `node-cache`.

Thanks again to [Kiliman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293609/kiliman) for providing the updated Singleton function.