# How to periodically fetch inside a loader with Remix.run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, remix.run

There is an API with data that I need for my app, but I can only call it a few times a minute. This data is also shared between all users (think getting the current Bitcoin price, for example).

So I want to call the API once every minute on the server-side, cache it, and then serve the result whenever someone loads the page. In short, I want to do something like this, but I am not sure how to structure it:

```js
export const loader = async () => {
  let result;
  if (timeToFetch) {
    result = await getDataFromCache();
  } else {
    result = await getDataFromAPI();
  }
  return json(result);
};
```

My question is how to structure this `timeToFetch` functionality with Remix. Do I need some kind of long-running function? How do I do that with Remix?

I want to keep it simple and not have to use a database. What's the easiest/simplest way to do this?

Some reference:
[How do I use in-memory cache in Remix.run dev mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72661999/how-do-i-use-in-memory-cache-in-remix-run-dev-mode)

Answer (score 0):

This is what Remix calls "not a remix question" ;)

Though it does depend on what your deployment target is.

The main idea is that you create a class or storage that keeps does the track keeping, and you import that into your loader, or put it on Remix context. This is "just" like you would do in nodejs normally.

I'm giving you an example for the node/express server.

1. You can create a file called `PriceCache.js`

   ```
   // I'm using types to make the intent clearer
   type Price = { bitcoin_to_usd: number }

   const FETCH_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 5 // 5 minutes

   class PriceCache {
     last_promise: Promise<Price>
     constructor() {
       // I'm just keeping the last fetch promise, so when a fetch just
       // happened, requests might have to wait a bit
       // You can change this to also store the last value directly
       this.last_promise = this.fetchPrice()

       // This will "just" run in the background
       setInterval(() => {
         this.last_promise = this.fetchPrice()
       }, FETCH_INTERVAL)
     }

     private async fetchPrice() {
       // *Whatever you want to do to fetch the price*
       const response = await fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
       const json = await response.json()
       return json.bpi.USD.rate_float
     }
   }

   // Create an instance, so it starts loading when this file is imported
   export let price_cache = new PriceCache()
   ```

   This is just an example, you can do anything you want in here.
2. Import the file into your server.entry.js

   ```
   import "./caches/PriceCache"
   ```

   You don't even have to import anything from it, but you can if you want!
   Just with this import, the cache will now run in the background.
3. In your loader, import and use the `price_cache`:

   ```
   import { price_cache } from "../caches/PriceCache"

   export async function loader() {
     // Though still using `await`, most of the time this will be instantaneous
     let prices = await price_cache.last_promise

     return { prices }
   }
   ```

As you can see, the remix part very small.
You can write any node in your remix app and use it.

#### But I'm using a serverless backend

Then it depends on your backend again!

For example with cloudflare, you might use a [KV store](https://developers.cloudflare.com/kv/learning/how-kv-works/) or [Durable Objects](https://developers.cloudflare.com/durable-objects/) with [CRON triggers](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/configuration/cron-triggers/). That would make it a lot less simple and introduce some kind of database though ;)

[Cloudflare on using longer-lived resources in your Remix loader function](https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/framework-guides/deploy-a-remix-site/#binding-resources-to-your-remix-application)

#### Using it in development mode

A cache like this will reload every time you change anything while in development. [This answer can help you circumvent that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72661999/how-do-i-use-in-memory-cache-in-remix-run-dev-mode) Just be cautious, as any changes you make to the cache won't reflect this way either. You wouldn't be the first person to spend hours to realise your cache was... cached ;)